# different types of sorting and their time

Tags: java, sorting

I know that as number of elements is doubled the time to sort for selection sort and insertion sort quadrupled.

How about merge sort and quick sort?
Lets say it makes 2 seconds to sort 100 items using merge sort.
How long would it take to sort 200 items using merge sort and quick sort?

Answer (score 0):

Merge Sort is usually O(nlog(n)).  Quick sort can be O(nlog(n)), but worst case scenario it will end up closer to O(n^2).  I'll leave the math to you, as it's fairly simple.  The nice thing about common sorting algorithms is that they are very well documented online, there are likely plenty of calculators online that could give you specifics.  As for how long it would actually take to run an algorithm, I'm no expert but I'm guessing that would depend largely on hardware.  You should be more concerned with the Big-O of whatever you're running because that's the only thing you can really control as a programmer.